# How to use Material Designs "Standard" bottomsheet in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am trying to use Googles bottomsheet in an iOS app (Xamarin, which means it's written in C#). I've managed to use the "modal" variant, which dims the view behind it when it appears, but what I need is a bottomsheet that works as the one in the Google Maps app - allowing manipulation of both the area "below" the bottomsheet, as well as the content of the bottomsheet itself.

I've gotten a nuGet which contains a bunch of Material Design components (Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponents), but I haven't been able to find any documentation saying how the "clickthrough" bottomsheet can be achieved. When making the (Xamarin) Android version of this app, I've managed to achieve a "clickthrough" bottomsheet - but in Android this comes in the form of something called a BottomSheetBehavior, which is attached to a child of a CoordinatorLayout. -This has me stumped, as there is (AFAIK) no corresponding layout-construct in iOS.

This piece of code constructs a new viewController with some content, and displays it in a bottomsheet which slides up above the current view. -All very well, but does anybody have any idea of how to make the background view "manipulable"?

```
UIViewController content = new UIViewController();
content.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
content.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
Button b = new Button();
b.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 100, 20);
b.SetTitle("A Button appears!", UIControlState.Normal);
content.Add(b);

BottomSheetController bs = new BottomSheetController(content);         
bs.PreferredContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(300, 300);
PresentViewController(bs,true,null);
```

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: I searched the document and apis of BottomSheetController, it seems that you can't achieve that in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UIAlertController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uialertcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) for this if I am not wrong

All you have to do is something like this:

```
var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Option!", "Option!?", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
```

And then just present it

```
PresentViewController (alert, animated: true, completionHandler: null);
```

For more information check the microsoft docs,

Good luck.

Feel free to get back if you have queries